# Factorize $x(y^2 - z^2) + y(z^2 - x^2) + z(x^2 - y^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, multivariate-polynomial

I know the answer is $-(y-z)(x-y)(x-z) = (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ via WolframAlpha.

However, I don't why that's the solution nor how to get it "by hand". (nor what specific area of math I can find the proof and/or algorithm).

Comment: Hint: One way to see that $x-y$ is a factor is to plug in $y=x$ and see that it evaluates to $0$.

Comment: Try to apply difference of two squares here.

Comment: If you don't ["see"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357264/factorize-xy2-z2-yz2-x2-zx2-y2#comment9097323_4357264) it right away, just factor it the hard way, as you would factor any quadratic in $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On expanding:

$x(y^2 - z^2) + y(z^2 - x^2) + z(x^2 - y^2)=xy^2-xz^2+yz^2-yx^2+zx^2-zy^2 $

$=xy^2-yx^2+yz^2-xz^2+zx^2-zy^2$

$=xy(y-x)+z^2(y-x)+z(x^2-y^2)$

$=(x-y)(zx-z^2+zy-xy)$

$=(x-y)(z(x-z)+y(z-x))$

$=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$